# 1000+ Game-Objects in Vector too slow? What is my mistake?

Tags: c++, object, for-loop, vector, render

I am currently working on a game, where there is a need for keeping track of lot of objects.

I have a game object class, which holds all the necessary information of the object and handles AI() on update();

I decided, that only objects with a brain, will need an update every frame. So I have separated vectors to save time. However, I cannot seem to find a similar solution when drawing objects. So I got

```
std::vector<cOBJECT*> LivingObjects;
```

and

```
std::vector<cOBJECT*> WorldObjects;
```

When drawing all objects, I first put all of the objects in a RenderList:

```
//Add World and Living Objects into one list of RenderObjects
RenderObjects = WorldObjects;
RenderObjects.insert(RenderObjects.end(), LivingObjects.begin(), LivingObjects.end());
```

Then I sort them by Y:

```
//Sort all Objects by Y (bottom) Coordiante
sort(RenderObjects.begin(), RenderObjects.end(), cmd);
```

Here is the code for that (maybe this is slow too?:

```
//Sorts by Y-Coordinaté
bool cmd(cOBJECT* obj1, cOBJECT* obj2)
{
    return obj1->getrect().y + obj1->getrect().h < obj2->getrect().y + obj2->getrect().h;
}
```

Then I draw them. The drawing function will check if they are on screen on or not! So I only draw visible objects:

```
//DRAW OBJECTS and 
for (std::vector<cOBJECT*>::size_type i = 0; i != RenderObjects.size(); i++)
{
    RenderObjects[i]->render(Renderer, CameraX, CameraY, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
}
```

Here is the actual draw function´:

```
int cTEXTURES::renderAnimation(int targetX, int targetY, double angle, SDL_Point* center, SDL_RendererFlip flip, SDL_Renderer* Renderer, int row, int speed, int offX, int offY, int SCREEN_HEIGHT, int SCREEN_WIDTH)
{
    //Draw if part of it shown on screen
    if (targetX - offX >= -FrameWidth && targetX - offX <= SCREEN_WIDTH + FrameWidth && targetY - offY >= -FrameHeight && targetY - offY <= SCREEN_HEIGHT + FrameHeight)
    {
        SDL_Rect SourceRect;
        SDL_Rect TargetRect;

        TargetRect = { targetX - offX, targetY - offY, FrameWidth, FrameHeight };

        SourceRect.x = (CurrentFrame - 1) * FrameWidth;
        SourceRect.y = (row - 1) * FrameHeight;
        SourceRect.w = FrameWidth;
        SourceRect.h = FrameHeight;

        if (OldTime + speed > SDL_GetTicks()) { SDL_RenderCopyEx(Renderer, TheTextureManager::Instance()->TextureList[TexturePath], &SourceRect, &TargetRect, angle, center, flip); return 0; }

        OldTime = SDL_GetTicks();

        //SDL_RenderCopyEx(Renderer, TheTextureManager::Instance()->TextureList[TexturePath], &SourceRect, &TargetRect, angle, center, flip);
        TheTextureManager::Instance()->draw(TexturePath, Renderer, &SourceRect, &TargetRect, angle, center, flip);
        CurrentFrame++;

        if (CurrentFrame == (Frames + 1))
        {
            CurrentFrame = 1;
            return 1; // returns 1 if one row is finished
        }

        return 0; // returns 0 if animation is not finished
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now I got 1000+ objects, probably even 2000+ later on. Just running through the for-loop to check if the objects need to be drawn is very time-intensive, right?

What am I missing? How can I keep track of 1000s of objects and know whether to draw them without such extensive amount of work for the CPU? Especially because I will need a lot of room for a lot of AI

Thanks, this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Can you profile your program?

Comment: @Axalo: I am using  Visual C++ Express. It does not allow me to as far as I know.

Comment: You *are* measuring a Release build, right?

Comment: @Angew omg! now I got like 700 FPS with 1000+ objects. Please tell me, how exactly does this happen? Debug so much slower? Thanks

Comment: debug has almost all optimizations disabled

Comment: @Creris Thanks! I got it all running over 1300FPS now with some extra tuning. I will learn more about my compiler settings soon

Comment: In a nutshell: Debug is geared towards the closest possible correspondence between source code and binary (so that you can tell which statement is executing), and there are loads of safety checks (null smart pointer dereferencing, all local vars initialised, bounds checking etc.). Release is geared towards execution speed to the exclusion of everything else.

Comment: @Angew This hint saved me from madness today.

Comment: @Angew, thanks i wasted 4 hours trying to figure out why i'm not getting even constant 60 FPS, now on release i'm getting 700 FPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For speeding up iterators of stl containers in debug builds (and compile times due to header parsing) include the following lines in the first header (or precompiled header) before anything else is included (such as the "windows.h" header):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS  // disable the Microsoft specific warnings about _s buffer underrun security issues for ISO methods (fopen, strcpy etc..)
#   define VC_EXTRALEAN             // cut down includes
#   define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN      // cut down includes
#   undef _SECURE_SCL               // iterators generate less overhead code in debug
#   if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0
#       define _SECURE_SCL 1
#   else
#       define _SECURE_SCL 0
#   endif
#endif
```

The _iterator_debug_level setting can be a bit tricky if you link to other libraries that have different iterator_debug_levels.

This will make your debug builds run a lot faster, but if performance is required, it is often the usage of the containers that needs a second look, and finally rolling your own containers is the last resort if your operations are complex or specific.